# How to resolve - CircleCI automated job hangs/fails Parcel build with CSS Import

Tags: javascript, circleci, parceljs

## React/Parcel/Jest/CircleCI

Setting up CI - The **automated** build job will hang then fail on the build step when we have imported a CSS file in our app via 
import "../resoures/fonts/style.css"

### Scenarios:

The build command executes successfully when:

- Run locally
- SSH into CircleCI container and run build
- Automated CircleCI job will execute if we **remove** the css import line (below)

**CSS Import**

```
import type { Node } from "react";
import { Router } from "@reach/router";
import { Login } from "./pages/login";
import "../resources/fonts/style.css";


type Props = {};
export default class App extends React.Component<Props> {
  render(): Node {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Login path={"/"} />
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

**CircleCI config.yml**

```
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: "circleci/node:8"
    working_directory: ~/repo
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: "npm install"
      - run: # run linter
          name: lint
          command: npm run lint
      - run: # run flow
          name: flow
          command: npx flow
      - run: # run tests
          name: tests
          command: npm test
      - run: # run build
          name: build
          command: npm run build
```

ErrorMessage from CI job (with CSS import)

```
>parcel build index.html

Too long with no output (exceeded 10m0s)"
```

Answer (score 2):

Circle CI stops a running step after 10 minutes of inactivity. This means if no output is written to the console during this period the job is canceled and marked as failed. However you can customize this threshold by using the *no_output_timeout* configuration option.

```
   jobs:
      build:
   ...
        steps:
   ...
          - run: # run build
              name: build
              command: npm run build
              no_output_timeout: 60m
```

See the documentation for more information: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#run